# Cloud Kit how to re fetch records when error

Tags: swift3, icloud, cloudkit

Cloud WWDC says When you get a `CKError.changeTokenExpired`  re-fetch changes by setting the previous server change token to nil. I tried something like this:

```
let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation()
operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
operation.recordZoneIDs = appDelegate.changedZoneIDs

let fetchOptions = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
fetchOptions.previousServerChangeToken = nil
operation.optionsByRecordZoneID = [ recordZoneID : fetchOptions]
```

But the `optionsByRecordZoneID` has been deprecated. So how can I pass the previous server token to the server and continue fetching past the error handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the instance property configurationsByRecordZoneID on your CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation().

How about:

```
let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation()
operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
operation.recordZoneIDs = appDelegate.changedZoneIDs

let fetchOptions = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration()
fetchOptions.previousServerChangeToken = nil

var zoneConfiguration: [CKRecordZone.ID : CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration] = [:]
for zoneID in operation.recordZoneIDs {
    zoneConfiguration[zoneID] = fetchOptions
}
operation.configurationsByRecordZoneID = zoneConfiguration
```